# Adding tables with different schema such as [Schema].[TableName] using AMO.

Tags: sql, schema, ssas, tabular

I am trying to add table with different schema such as [Schema].[TableName] but I am unable to do it. This works fine for tables with dbo schema.

Where in the code should I add the specific schema info so that I can get the schema for the tables in the dataSourceView?